# Sparkline charts are misleading

Tags: javascript, jquery, sparklines

I am using sparklines charts from omnipotent.net to display statistical information. The problem is that the lowest value in a data series, is always shown on the charts as if it's zero.

For instance, if I have a bar chart with 3 bars, and they have the values 4, 2 and 5, the lowest value (2) would look like it's zero on the bar chart (look at the picture to see what I mean).

I know that it's possible to set the "chartRangeMin" option in order to avoid the problem, but I am not using javascript to make the chart, but rather HTML.

Here is my code:

```
<div class='sparkline' data-type='bar' data-bar-color='#338ce8' data-bar-width='42' data-height='22'>1.37, 1.55, 1.66</div><ul class='list-inline text-muted axis'><li>2007</li><li>2008</li><li>2009</li></ul>
```

The question if, how do I use Javascript to set the "chartRangeMin" to another value than zero?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin, but I would imagine it's a setting somewhere to change the minimum Y axis value.

Comment: The syntax is explained on the following link, but this kind of thing is not my strongest suit, maybe you can see how to set the "chartRangeMin" option: [link](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#syntax)

Comment: `data-chart-range-min=0`

Comment: From that documentation it's the `chartRangeMin` which you should set to `0`. Or you can use the `data` attribute, as @Shaun mentioned

Comment: Shaun, you should post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it as an answer... because you're right :-)

Answer (score 3):

From the jQuery Sparklines documentation, on Line Graphs you can set the `chartRangeMinX`. This will allow you to set a minimum value for the X axis.

http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#syntax